# how to give textox dynamically at runtime in mvc4 bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, html.textboxfor

HI i am new to mvc and bootstrap..  i want to dynamically add two text box at run time in mvc4 and bootstrap..  i have tried many sites but i am not able to understand. please give me simple example

i have tried this

In model

```
 public class Gift
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
```

in controller

```
public ActionResult PanelEx()
        {

            var initialData = new[] {
        new Gift { Name = "Tall Hat", Price = 39.95 },
        new Gift { Name = "Long Cloak", Price = 120.00 },
    };
            return View(initialData);

        }
```

what should i wrote in model. how to do next step..i am stuck PLese help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult PanelEx()
{
    var initialData = new List<Gift>{
    new Gift { Name = "Tall Hat", Price = 39.95 },
    new Gift { Name = "Long Cloak", Price = 120.00 },
};
    return View(initialData);
}

@model IEnumerable<Gift>

<div>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(item=>item.Name)
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: hey thanks you so much.. instead of @Html.TextBoxFor(item=>item.Name) use @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem =>item.Name)

Comment: can u please tel me how to bring empty textbox dynamically